# Query table using inner join?

Tags: sql, inner-join

We are trying to find the names of the customers who have both a loan and an account in the same branch. Should we use `inner join` here? So far we have only written;

```
select DISTINCT customer.name
FROM Customer, Has_Loan, Branch, Has_Account 
WHERE
```

[image]

We have tried a few different things without getting any further, so appreciate any kind of help or hint:)

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: I can't read that tiny image text. Besides, most people here want formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customer.Name
FROM Customer
    INNER JOIN Has_Account ON Customer.Ssn = Has_Account.Assn
    INNER JOIN Account ON Account.AccountNo = Has_Account.ANo
    INNER JOIN Has_Loan ON Customer.Ssn = Has_Loan.Lssn
    INNER JOIN Loan ON Loan.LoanNo = Has_Loan.LNo
WHERE Loan.BranchID = Account.BranchID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select c.name
from customer c
join has_loan hl on hl.lssn = c.ssn
join loan l on hl.lno = l.loanno
join has_account ha on ha.assn = c.ssn
join account a on ha.ano = a.accountno
join branch b on b.branchid = a.branchid
where l.branchid  = a.branchid
group by c.name;
```